# MS Access Form: entering new info into two linked tables without the keys

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables, say Employees (employeeID, employeeName, locationID) and Locations (locationID, locationName). What is the most efficient way to view existing records and also add new ones while not typing foreign keys?

For instance, if i create a query on a join between the two, I can insert a new record, but I need to type a locationID. Is there a way for me to have a drop-down box with locationName values instead? I know I can do it in a code, but would be nice to do it via Query or Form without coding.

Comment: Did you do a quick google search? https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/613186-passing-value-combo-box-query

Comment: I know you can do it in many ways, I was just curious about the easiest "standard" way. The answer provided below is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a basic form with your `Employees` table as a `Record Source`.

Add a text box for your `EmployeeID` and `EmployeeName`.

Add a combo box for your `LocationID`.  When you add the combo box it should start a wizard up - tell it you want the info from the `Locations` table and hide the key field.

Open your form and start entering data.